# SocketIOの認証

Tags: swift, iphone, node.js, websocket, socket.io

iPhoneアプリとNodeJS(SocketIO)でチャットのアプリケーションを作成している者です。

アプリ側からチャットサーバに接続するときに認証機能を導入したいと考えています。

サーバ側で下記のように実装しました。

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    var token = handshakeData.query.token;

    checkAuthToken(token, callback);
});
```

しかし、アプリ側でtokenをどこに設定したら良いのか分からず困っています。

```
var socket:SIOSocket! = nil

SIOSocket.socketWithHost("ServerUrl" , response: { (_socket: SIOSocket!) in
    self.socket = _socket

    println(self.socket)

    self.socket.onConnect = {() in
      println("connected")

    }
})
```

お知恵を拝借願えませんでしょうか?

(Server-side) · NodeJS (v0.10.26) - Socket.io@1.3.6

(Client side) · Swift1.6 - SIOSocket · Xcode6.4